# class file for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am working on the spring boot and keycloak.
here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>        
        <relativePath/>  
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mongodb.version>3.6.0-beta1</mongodb.version>      
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>   

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


import org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

@KeycloakConfiguration
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        //La methode keycloakAuthenticationProvider() herite de la classe KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
        //La gestion des utilisateurs et les roles Keycloak qui va le gérer
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        //pour accé à /prods l'utilisateur doit etre authentifié
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/products/**").hasAuthority("PRODUCT_MANAGER");
    }
}
```

when running the spring boot application, it comes with an error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/xisizhe/Documents/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/config/KeycloakSecurityConfig.java:[29,8] cannot access org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer
  class file for org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer not found
```

I don't know what goes wrong with it, anyone know the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has a "starter" dependency named `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` that supports Spring Boot. You need to add that dependency and `spring-boot-starter-security` as well.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
     <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```